# Where can I get better Apple documentation?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

More often than I'd have hoped I seem to come across method/property definitions in Apple's documentation that are vague at best and meaningless, to me, at worst. For example, take the following method description from `NSNumberFormatter Class Reference`:

---

> **setPartialStringValidationEnabled:**
>
> Sets whether partial string validation
>   is enabled for the receiver.
>
> ```
> - (void)setPartialStringValidationEnabled:(BOOL)b
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *b* YES if partial string validation is enabled, otherwise NO.

---

So, let's just assume that the shoddy educational system I went through and any previous projects I've worked on didn't cover "partial string validation" in Cocoa and I would like to dig into it some more to see what this property is all about. Where does one look (aside from Google)? I hate to pester forums for something I *should* be able to look up *easily* myself.

I have come across situations like this enough times now that I think I may be approaching Apple's docs incorrectly. Any suggestions? Tips/tricks? 3rd party resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setter methods like that are sometimes explained in more detail in the getter method, the introduction text in class documentation, or one of the documentation companion guides you see linked on the bottom left. Sometimes you can also find clues in the Cocoa headers, by right-clicking on the name when you're writing code and selecting 'jump to definition'.

Otherwise, there's really no other resource other than google, asking about it on sites like this or using a mailing list. You could always write some code to test what happens when you change its value. And of course, if it's something really confusing it's good too to take the time to file a radar bug report so it will hopefully be improved in the future.

Comment: And don't forget to file a bug with Apple under documentation if you feel it's insufficient

Answer (score 5):

Partial string validation [is explained in NSFormatter class](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFormatter/isPartialStringValid:newEditingString:errorDescription:).

Comment: Now why couldn't Apple provide a link to that info from their "description" of setPartialStringValidationEnabled:?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps it's omission, editor of manual thinks it's obvious or apple wants to keep reference manual as short as possible.
Each page has "Did this document help you?" box, and that's probably best place to complain.

Comment: Also, the partial string validation is mentioned in the Data Formatting Programming Guide. I've found that the high level guides are worth at least skimming before going through the class documentation